# Why Is My React Application Suddenly Not Working Locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application I have not started up locally, in over a year. This application ran perfectly last time I started it up.  And the application continues to run today in Heroku's cloud. But I want to work on it locally, and using the exact same package.json when it ran just fine a year ago, is now failing in the browser with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined
```

[Screenshot Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue5av.jpg)

I have tried deleting my node_modules directory, and deleting any non yarn.lock files, but the error persists.

I KNOW one of you intelligent folks can help. 
I'd greatly appreciate it.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mazzo-react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-lock": "^10.24.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "konva": "^1.7.6",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.7",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10",
    "react-konva": "^1.7.16",
    "react-relay": "0.10.0",
    "react-relay-network-layer": "1.3.9",
    "react-router": "3.0.2",
    "react-router-relay": "0.13.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "relay-commit-mutation-promise": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.4.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cj63i9kajpzhw0153segab1wa node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: One of your packages is using `react-reconciler` that is then using `ReactSharedInternals`, that has this -> `__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` , Also `react-reconciler` has -> `Use it at your own risk.`, and yet there are 106 dependants of this package,  mind boggles..

Comment: A quick check, oh dear -> `ReactKonva` is using `react-reconciler`. :(

Comment: @Keith, I appreciate your thoughtful response.  This is a project I followed along with watching Lynda.com.  So this is the way the project was setup.  What do you recommend I do to fix this?  Thanks,

Comment: It might be worth contacting the dev's at react-konva,.. https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva  Let them know,  Ideally having a depenancy on a package that has `Use it at your own risk.` doesn't sound good, they might be able to do whatever there doing without using it.

Comment: Really? This is what I have to do?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the route I would have taken after a small probe into the react-konva library. It's silly I know but it's how the system works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of your dependencies made a breaking change and either your own package.json or one of the dependencies you work with did not restrict the version of the dependencies you rely on. I would suggest checking the individual libraries throwing the error to make sure that the configuration you passed for those libraries are still valid for the version you are using.

Comment: so check on react-konva?

Comment: Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: From what I can see, check react-reconciler and react-konva